# How to show/hide DIVs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I want to make a function to show and hide a div tag and hide all others:

```
function showPage(showdiv){
    $('#midRight').not(showdiv).hide(); 
    $(showdiv).show();  
}
```

Link calling the function:

```
<ul>
  <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showPage('#home_page1')">
    <li>Show Page 1</li>
  </a>
  <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="showPage('#home_page2')">
    <li>Show Page 2</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

`DIV`s on page:

```
<div id="midRight">
    <div id="home_page1">Content 1</div>
    <div id="home_page2" style="display:none;">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

The function `showPage` ends up hiding every div within `midRight`, while on [JSFiddle, the click event doesn't seem to be handled at all](http://jsfiddle.net/ACGMj/).

What is the correct way to show/hide a DIV with jQuery?

Comment: Why are you appending `showdiv` to two empty strings? Just curious...

Comment: Wouldn't `function showPage(){$('#midRight div').toggle();
}` suffice?

Comment: @j08691 Only if they were in contradicting initial states.

Comment: @Crush - I changed it back; it was just to see if it would help but obviously made no difference! j08691 only if there are two list items and no more...

Comment: [Here's a version without the old-fashioned "onfoo" event handler attributes.](http://jsfiddle.net/mhpqQ/)

Comment: Agree, would be better to use Unobtrusive Javascript as Pointy has pointed out.

Comment: Also wrapping your `<li>` elements in `<a>` tags isn't really valid HTML.

Comment: ^ Should be other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write you selector to hide all child div's of `midRight`, then show the div with the passed ID. No need to cast to a String, since that is what you are passing:

```
function showPage(showdiv){
    $('#midRight > div').hide()  
    $(showdiv).show();    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed up some syntax errors. As the comments say, you're appending an empty string with the variable, just use the variable. Also, you need to tell the selector to select the children of the targetted container:

```
function showPage(showdiv){
    $('#midRight').children().not(showdiv).hide();  
    $(showdiv).show();  
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ACGMj/1/

Comment: Because there's the explicit ".show()" on the target, there's really no point to exclude it from the ".hide()".

Comment: @Pointy I guess that depends on if it's more efficient to select an additional element (and exclude it) than it is to apply the styling to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kc6qN/)

```
function showPage(showdiv){
    $(showdiv).show().siblings().hide();
}
```

Or, without using IDs:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jqgLf/)

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('#midRight > div').hide().eq(index).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle isn't working because it can't find the function, it can't find the function because you specified the functions to be interpreted during `onLoad`.  To fix it, in the upper left of the jsFiddle, set the dropdown from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <body>`.

Here's a working version that doesn't use in-line events:

http://jsfiddle.net/gRDdC/

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="nav-link" href="#home_page1">Show Page 1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="nav-link" href="#home_page2">Show Page 2</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<div id="midRight">
    <div id="home_page1">Content 1</div>
    <div id="home_page2" style="display:none;">Content 2</div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#midRight > div').hide();
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    });
});
```