# How to create function that swaps divs with different ids?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create function in js to swap content of webpage using .style.display = "none" or "block" but the main problem is that there are few different divs with different id's for that. The main aim of doing this is chagning content after clicking specific buttons without loading new page. The biggest problem for me is creating script which will change "id" 
independently of what id was before. Normally I could write all of id's one by one and just swap them but this is not the case. Content should be changed automatically so no matter what id was before it will replace for specific one after pressing button.

I have tried with `querySelector` in many ways by changing `id` with `class`, by using remove / set Attribute but none of these methods work for me. Im trying to write this fuction for 2 weeks and I don't have any ideas.

I'm worried that bootstrap classes may cause problem with this...

Can someone help me with this? Any tips?

This is my first post here so if I did something wrong, sorry for that.

I cannot paste here my code as everything is on my company laptop which I left when I was finish my job.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410210/how-to-show-hide-divs-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Here is an agnostic approach using no `HTML` `id`s or `class`es.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const buttons = container.querySelectorAll('button');
const divs = container.querySelectorAll(':scope > div');

function handleButtonClick() {
  this.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis sed, dicta quasi in blanditiis nam atque odio, nobis a. Eos incidunt debitis tenetur rerum, esse ratione quisquam possimus quasi nam.</p>
    <button>Toggle Content</button>    
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis sed, dicta quasi in blanditiis nam atque odio, nobis a. Eos incidunt debitis tenetur rerum, esse ratione quisquam possimus quasi nam.</p>
    <button>Toggle Content</button>    
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis sed, dicta quasi in blanditiis nam atque odio, nobis a. Eos incidunt debitis tenetur rerum, esse ratione quisquam possimus quasi nam.</p>
    <button>Toggle Content</button>    
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis sed, dicta quasi in blanditiis nam atque odio, nobis a. Eos incidunt debitis tenetur rerum, esse ratione quisquam possimus quasi nam.</p>
    <button>Toggle Content</button>    
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis sed, dicta quasi in blanditiis nam atque odio, nobis a. Eos incidunt debitis tenetur rerum, esse ratione quisquam possimus quasi nam.</p>
    <button>Toggle Content</button>    
  </div>  
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xL6k5qw/)

Comment: Your agnostic approach is a bit "dangerous" (specially the `this.previousElementSibling` part), the idea is OK-ish, but `button`, on a page, could be **any button** :) I see you used `divs` but you never filtered them in search for one. A quick-fix would be to also use `('.container > div > button')` but also... `.container` is a too general selector.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I answered the question in the simplest, most direct way I could. I don't want to overwhelm the questioner with too many details. A lot of the code we write here is conceptual. I agree with you on the `button` though and will address that.

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/1nt9bfm3/ that's how I'd approach the problem. I've also made sure not to toggle a contextual `<p>` but rather a block `<div>` that can eventually encompass multiple paragraphs, headings and so on...

Comment: Also, be careful in using the `:scope` selector.

Comment: Thanks for every response ! I really appreciate it. I will add my piece of code which Im struggling the most tomorrow. I need to carefully analyze your ideas as this is a bit complicated for me. I've just started my adventure with coding few months ago and now Im creating portfolio... so mine experience is not especially big.

Comment: @Xaarr Best of luck. We're here to help.