# How to define if statements for this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a toggle burger menu. I want to tell this code to hide `<div class="line1"></div>` and `<div class="line3"></div>` when the `.menu` is clicked.

How can I do this?

```js
$(function(){

  $('.menu').click(function(){
    $('.sidebar').toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
.menu {
background:#ddd;
padding:15px;
width:fit-content;
height:fit-content;
  position:relative;
}

.menu > div {
  background-color:black;
  width:22px;
  height:1px;
}

.line1 {
  top:12px;
  position:absolute;
}
.line2 {
  top:16px;
}
.line3 {
  top:22px;
}
.sidebar {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  
  
  
    <div class="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show/hide DIVs with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410210/how-to-show-hide-divs-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery **`.hide()`**

If you want to show it again, use **`.show()`** the same way you used **`.hide()`**

Go to the following links to learn more

**Hide:** http://api.jquery.com/hide/

**Show:** http://api.jquery.com/show/

I updated your snippet below:

```js
$(function(){

  $('.menu').click(function(){
    $('.sidebar').toggle();
    $(".line1").hide();
    $(".line3").hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.menu {
background:#ddd;
padding:15px;
width:fit-content;
height:fit-content;
  position:relative;
}

.menu > div {
  background-color:black;
  width:22px;
  height:1px;
}

.line1 {
  top:12px;
  position:absolute;
}
.line2 {
  top:16px;
}
.line3 {
  top:22px;
}
.sidebar {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  
  
  
    <div class="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
```

Or you can use **`.toggle()`**

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```js
$(function(){

  $('.menu').click(function(){
    $('.sidebar').toggle();
    $(".line1").toggle();
    $(".line3").toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
.menu {
background:#ddd;
padding:15px;
width:fit-content;
height:fit-content;
  position:relative;
}

.menu > div {
  background-color:black;
  width:22px;
  height:1px;
}

.line1 {
  top:12px;
  position:absolute;
}
.line2 {
  top:16px;
}
.line3 {
  top:22px;
}
.sidebar {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  
  
  
    <div class="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it hide and then show, use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), like this:

```js
$(function(){

  $('.menu').click(function(){
    $('.sidebar').toggle();
    $(".line1").toggle();
    $(".line3").toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
.menu {
background:#ddd;
padding:15px;
width:fit-content;
height:fit-content;
  position:relative;
}

.menu > div {
  background-color:black;
  width:22px;
  height:1px;
}

.line1 {
  top:12px;
  position:absolute;
}
.line2 {
  top:16px;
}
.line3 {
  top:22px;
}
.sidebar {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  
  
  
    <div class="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
```