# How to show only one div at the time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got three sections, inside of which there are two divs. Inside the first one I have a button and after clicking it I should have the next one opened. However, only one div should be visible at the time (so when you click the next one, previous one should be closed). And I've got this functionality, but after clicking on the button again - it doesn't close the corresponding div.

I set up an example of my problem on codepen:

```
https://codepen.io/hubertstrawa/pen/abOwWMJ
```

```
<section>
  <div class="product">
    <span class="btn">Show more</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product-more displayNone">
    Test
  </div>
</section>
```

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {

  // only one div to be shown but can't be closed as well.
  $('.product-more').each(function(i, v) {
  $(this).removeClass('displayBlock');
  $(this).addClass('displayNone');
  })

  if ($(e.target).parent().next().hasClass('displayNone')) {
    $(e.target).parent().next().removeClass('displayNone');
    $(e.target).parent().next().addClass('displayBlock');
  } else {
    $(e.target).parent().next().removeClass('displayBlock');
    $(e.target).parent().next().addClass('displayNone');
  }

});
```

Any ideas how can I make it work?

Thank you

Comment: you can use .show(), .hide(), and .toggle() with jquery

Comment: Include your div element on question as well.

Comment: I've just included it thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show/hide DIVs with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410210/how-to-show-hide-divs-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change a `.is-open` on a parent element**.

```
<section class="product is-open">    <!-- is-open toggled by JS -->
    <div class="product-more"></div> <!-- handle children styles using CSS -->
</section>
```

```
                 .product-more { display: none; }  /* default */
.product.is-open .product-more { display: block; } /* when ancestor is .is-open*/
```

Use **delegateTarget** inside the `.on()` method to get back the `.product` delegator element

```js
const $product = $('.product'); // Collect all current products

$product.on('click', '.btn', function(e) {

  const $thisProd = $(e.delegateTarget);          // The .product delegator
  $product.not($thisProd).removeClass('is-open'); // Handle all (but not this)
  $thisProd.toggleClass('is-open');               // Handle current

});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.product {
  background-color: #ededed;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.product-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.product .btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: .7rem;
  background-color: cyan;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-more {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: cyan;
  display: none; /* by default */
}

.product.is-open .product-more {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="product">
  <div class="product-title">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <span class="btn">Show more</span>
  </div>
  <div class="product-more">Test</div>
</section>

<section class="product">
  <div class="product-title">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <span class="btn">Show more</span>
  </div>
  <div class="product-more">Test</div>
</section>

<section class="product">
  <div class="product-title">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <span class="btn">Show more</span>
  </div>
  <div class="product-more">Test</div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is preferred, since it lets you change HTML and CSS, and not worry any more about JavaScript - whilst by using `.prev()`, `.next()` or `.parent()` (like the other answers suggest) JS is just waiting for you to change the markup - to break.

- No need to traverse back and forth your selectors.
- No need for `.displayNone` and `.displayBlock` on the *product-more* element.

---

## Handling dynamic `.product`

if your `.product` are dynamic elements, here's another solution to the above concept:

```js
$('.allProducts').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {

  const $product = $(e.delegateTarget).find('.product'); // Get all .product
  const $thisProd = $(this).closest('.product'); // The closest .product ancestor
  $product.not($thisProd).removeClass('is-open'); // Handle all (but not this)
  $thisProd.toggleClass('is-open'); // Handle current

});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.product {
  background-color: #ededed;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.product-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.product .btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: .7rem;
  background-color: cyan;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-more {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: cyan;
  display: none; /* by default */
}

.product.is-open .product-more {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="allProducts">

  <section class="product">
    <div class="product-title">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <span class="btn">Show more</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-more">Test</div>
  </section>

  <section class="product">
    <div class="product-title">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <span class="btn">Show more</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-more">Test</div>
  </section>

  <section class="product">
    <div class="product-title">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <span class="btn">Show more</span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-more">Test</div>
  </section>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you much!! I can see the benefits of this solution, the inner divs will likely be changed a little due to styling so I won't have to re-edit JS.

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding all the `product-more` sections when clicking any `btn` button, and then, trying to show/hide the `product-more` section associated with the clicked button.

So, when the section `product-more` is already shown and you click its `btn` button what happens is that you first hide the associated section and then your code checks if it is not visible and then shows its again.

One possible solution is to discard the associated `product-more` section when hiding. Also, as `div`s are shown by default, you don't need the `displayBlock` class.

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
    var $current = $(e.target).parent().next('.product-more');

    // Hide all sections that are not the one associated to the current button.
    $('.product-more').not($current).addClass('displayNone');

    // Show or hide current section.
    $current.toggleClass('displayNone');
});
```

Comment: @HubertStrawa the `displayBlock` class is absolutely not needed. Remove it from everywhere.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you're right, divs are on display block by default. Removed it and the code looks neater. Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer based on @RokoC.Buljan comment!

Comment: @HubertStrawa also, be more specific with your selectors, `$('.btn')` could be *any .btn* in your DOM - It's used really often.

Comment: @HubertStrawa also beware when using `.parent()` `.next()` `.prev()` etc. This is quite brittle and could easily break. See the last [paragraph explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60475141/383904)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toggleClass` it will detect your class and change it to another.

In your each function you just need to set all items to be hide and then it will toggle classes for current item.

Codepen

> https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/rNVwwLy?editors=1010

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {

  // only one div to be shown but can't be closed as well.
  $('.product-more').each(function(i, v) {
    $(this).removeClass('displayBlock');
    $(this).addClass('displayNone');
  })
 $(e.target).parent().next().toggleClass('displayNone displayBlock');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version using jQuery would be using [hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [toggle():](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
  var more = $(e.target).parent().next() ;
  $('.product-more').not(more).hide();
  $(e.target).parent().next().toggle();
});
```